# Who is right and who is wrong? Oracle certification OCP. Inconsistency in the choice of answers

Tags: java, oracle, enums, switch-statement, program-entry-point

What is printed by the following program?
`

```
public class Deer {
   enum Food {APPLES, BERRIES, GRASS}
   protected class Diet {
      private Food getFavorite() {
         return Food.BERRIES;
      }
   }
   public static void main(String[] seasons) {
      switch(new Diet().getFavorite()) {
         case APPLES: System.out.print("a");
         case BERRIES: System.out.print("b");
         default: System.out.print("c");
      }
   }
}
```

`
[image]

The answer image is from OCP Test bank, in which I prepare my Oracle certification exam

**My problem** is I can't agree with the answer, that the Oracle company considers correct

I think most correct and accurate option is **D**.

**My argument**: main method is not guilty for improper declaration of Diet class. Error is occur when we type this class in switch statement incorrectly, **in moment of declaration of class**

Even full answer in the image explained that

I created this question because every score on a paid exam is at stake

I thought professional commerce company treats the drafting of questions carefully

How an exam participant can deal in this situation?

I please you tell me is it common have such ambiguous answers in IT certification exams?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "main method is not guilty for improper *declaration of Diet class*." but inner `Diet` class was declared properly (if you remove `main` method you will see rest of code will compile fine). Problem is how it was *used* inside `main` method - since inner class requires instance of outer class to instantiated (here `Deer`). Did you perhaps confuse `Dear` and `Diet` while reading explanation? OR maybe declaration of class with creating its instance?

Comment: Why don't you just try it and see what the compilation error is?

Answer (score 2):

The answer E is the correct one. No matter what you think the answer ought to be, when I compile the code using `javac` (Java 8 and Java 16), the only compilation error is in the `main` method.

```
$ javac Deer.java 
Deer.java:9: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced
                    from a static context
      switch(new Diet().getFavorite()) {
             ^
1 error
$
```

The compilation error message is a bit odd ... but it is clearly in the `main` method.  You can repeat this experiment for yourself.

---

You state that you think that the declaration of `Diet` is improper, but I don't see anything improper about it.  It looks like a normal inner class declaration.

The problem in the code is NOT with the declaration of `Diet`, but in the way that the `main` method is attempting to create the `Diet` instance.  The (syntactically) correct way would be to write something like this (in `main`):

```
switch(new Deer().new Diet().getFavorite()) {
```

This says:

- create an instance of the outer class `Deer`
- create an instance of `Diet` in the `Deer` instance
- call the `getFavorite()` method on the `Diet` instance.

So ... clearly ... `main` is doing it wrong, and that is where the error is.  And the compiler agrees.

And the Java Language Specification ([JLS 15.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.2)) confirms this:

> If C is an inner member class, then:
>
> - If the class instance creation expression is unqualified, then:
>
>   - If the class instance creation expression occurs in a static context, then a compile-time error occurs.

<sup>(You won't find anything in the JLS to support your assertion that the declaration of `Diet` is wrong ... because it isn't wrong.  But feel free to research this, if you want to.)</sup>

---

Meta advice: Before going into a rant about the (supposed) problems with IT certification exams and the companies that administer them ... it is advisable to make sure that you have got your facts right.

The Java language has all sorts of obscure corners, and even after 20+ years of using it, I *still* keep find things about the language that I didn't realize (or have forgotten).  It is a bad idea to assume that that you are right ... in the face of possible evidence to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the declaration of the `Diet` class. It's the *usage* of the `Diet` class, not its declaration or definition, that causes the issue, and that usage is in `main()`. As the question points out, doing `new Deer().new Diet().getFavorite()` would be fine - so the `Diet` class compiled correctly.

I think what you're getting wrong here is the word "declaration". This is *not  ambiguous* - it has a very specific and technical meaning in compiled languages like C and Java.

- An object's **declaration** is when it's declared to exist by code. Often this is coupled with
- an object's **definition** describes *what* it is (almost always combined with the declaration, in Java; in C/C++, the declaration and definition are often split between `.h` and `.c` files).
- An object's **instantiation** is when the definition is invoked to create an instance of the object/variable in memory. Every instance (there may be multiple) will conform to the same definition.

The declaration and definition of `Diet` are fine, only the instantiation is wrong. Thus, answer (D) is incorrect.

---

Also, as pointed out in the other answer, if you try compiling this code with `javac`, the only compilation error is in the `main` method - again, because it's the *usage* of the `Diet` class that causes the problem, not the *definition*.